# Remedies if code takes too long, never gives resuluts

Tags: r, performance, lme4

**Updated**

This is the original structure of my data: all variables are explanatory variables except for people and activity and the dependent variable is completion.

```
   data.frame': 581755 obs. of  68 variables:
     **$ activity          : int  37033 37033 37033 37033 37033 37033 37033 37033 37033 37033 ...
     $ people         : int  5272 5272 5272 5272 5272 5272 5272 5272 5272 5272 ...
     $ completion: num 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     *$ active            : int  0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
     $ overdue           : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ wdsp              : num  5.7 5.7 7.7 6.4 3.9 5.8 3.5 6.3 4.8 9.4 ...
     $ rain              : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ UserCompletionRate: num [1:581755, 1] NaN -1.55 -1.55 -1.55 -1.55 ...
      ..- attr(*, "scaled:center")= num 0.462
      ..- attr(*, "scaled:scale")= num 0.298
     $ DayofWeekSu       : num  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ DayofWeekMo       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
     $ DayofWeekTu       : num  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
     $ DayofWeekWe       : num  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
     $ DayofWeekTh       : num  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
     $ DayofWeekFr       : num  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

     $ MonthofYearJan    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ MonthofYearFeb    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ MonthofYearMar    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ MonthofYearApr    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ MonthofYearMay    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ MonthofYearJun    : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ MonthofYearJul    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ MonthofYearAug    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ MonthofYearSep    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ MonthofYearOct    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ MonthofYearNov    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ cold              : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ hot               : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ overduetask       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...***
```

> My data relates if activities from people are completed or not and
>   affected by sunshine and all other variables posted  above -
>   `completion` is the outcome variable and `sunshine` would be the
>   explanatory variable; this is a simplified version.

```
 df <-  people = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5),
        activity = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,6),
        completion = c(0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1),
        sunshine = c(1,2,3,4,5,4,6,2,4,8,4)
```

so far I've use this code for the cloglog:

```
model<- as.formula("completion ~  sunshine")
clog_full = glm(model,data=df,family = binomial(link = cloglog))
summary(clog_full)


> using package glmmML
 model_re<- as.formula("completion ~  sunshine")
    > clog_re = glmmML(model_re,cluster = people, data= df,family =
    > binomial(link = cloglog)) summary(clog_re)
> 
> using package lme4
> 
> model_re1<- as.formula("completion ~  (1|people) + sunshine") clog_re1
> = glmer(model_re1, data=df,family = binomial(link = cloglog)) summary(clog_re1) summ(clog_re1, exp = TRUE)
```

Comment: how is this related to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62234957/random-intercept-glm-in-r) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've clearly not posted the code that hangs because we see this:

```
df <-  people = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5),
Error: unexpected ',' in "df <-  people = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5),"
```

You first need to put in the missing `data.frame` call if you expect a dataframe:

```
df <-  data.frame( people = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5),
activity = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,6),
completion = c(0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1),
sunshine = c(1,2,3,4,5,4,6,2,4,8,4) )
```

The rest of the code runs without difficulty if you put in the missing line breaks:

```
library(lme4)
  model_re1<- as.formula("completion ~  (1|people) + sunshine")
  clog_re1   = glmer(model_re1, data=df,family = binomial(link = cloglog)) 
  summary(clog_re1)
  summ(clog_re1, exp = TRUE)  # there is no function named `summ` so that throws an error but does not hang

library( glmmML)
  model_re<- as.formula("completion ~  sunshine")
  clog_re = glmmML(model_re,cluster = people, data= df,family =
                        binomial(link = cloglog)) 
  summary(clog_re)
```

Comment: @IRFTM i have tried to simplify my code for here, i will update it to my original code. I am glad that my code is at least right.

Comment: I didn't say it was "right". That would depend on what it was you were trying to analyze.  I said it did not cause my machine to hang.

Comment: @IRFTM true, i was happy that the code was not the reason for hanging, my dataset is half a million observations and i updated the other ivs included in my post. Any help is great.